# Parse text files from multiple folders and create new ones [shell]

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I have this folder structure...

```
171219_NB501241_0070_AHCHYNBGX5
├── fastq
│   ├── Reports
│   ├── Stats
│   ├── Undetermined_S0_R1_001.fastq.gz
│   └── Undetermined_S0_R2_001.fastq.gz
├── Logs
│   └── Logs.zip
├── Recipe
│   └── NS2932577-REAGT.xml
├── RTAComplete.txt
├── RTAConfiguration.xml
└── samplesheet.R70.csv
180201_NB501241_0088_AHJ2GHBGX5
├── fastq
│   ├── Reports
│   ├── Stats
│   ├── Undetermined_S0_R1_001.fastq.gz
│   └── Undetermined_S0_R2_001.fastq.gz
├── Logs
│   └── Logs.zip
├── Recipe
│   └── NS2951235-REAGT.xml
├── RTAComplete.txt
├── RTAConfiguration.xml
└── samplesheet.R88.csv
```

... there's a text file inside `Stats` from which I want to read some specific lines and generate a new text file within each `fastq` folder (`17121.../fastq/`).

Running these code lines...

```
for i in 70 88
>do cat *0${i}*/fastq/Stats/DemultiplexingStats.xml | grep -e "<Sample name" -e "<BarcodeCount" >> *0${i}*/fastq/rawcounts2
>done
```

... I'm having this error and I don't have any idea about what I'm missconsidering (if text redirection goes at the loop's end works well, but I want an specific file for each folder):

```
-bash: *070*/fastq/rawcounts2: No such file or directory
-bash: *088*/fastq/rawcounts2: No such file or directory
```

Thanks.

Comment: use find with -exec instead of for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- could be more than one file and/or directory matching the pattern `*0${i}*`
- matching directories may not contain the source file (`DemultiplexingStats.xml`)
- OP has confirmed the `grep` command returns the desired results (otherwise OP may want to provide a sample of the source file and the matching target file)

Modifying OP's current code:

```
for d in *070* *088*
do
    [ ! -d "${d}" ] && continue

    srcfile="${d}"/fastq/Stats/DemultiplexingStats.xml
    tgtfile="${d}"/fastq/rawcounts2

    [ ! -f "${srcfile}" ] && echo "WARNING: cannot find file '${srcfile}'. Skipping." && continue

    grep -e "<Sample name" -e "<BarcodeCount" "${srcfile}" >> "${tgtfile}"
done
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. I'd say the only problem is how I'm calling the folders... I'm a bit naive with shell, what's the difference between calling a folder without _*_ and add them later (as I did it) or using _*_ right in the beginning? (if I change my loop to `for i in *folder*...` format, it works nicely, but not if only `for i in folder...`). Thanks, markp-fuso.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
find . -path "*/fastq/Stats/DemultiplexingStats.xml" -execdir grep -e "<Sample name" -e "<BarcodeCount" '{}' >> ../rawcounts2 \;
```

FInd all files ending with "/fastq/Stats/DemultiplexingStats.xml" and then within the directory of the found files, execute the grep commands on the files found and output to a rawcounts2 file in a directory one level up from the current one.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Raman. That's works nicely but I forgot to clarify that I want a _rawcounts2_ not in a previous level but a **specific and individual** one inside each `fastq` folder (each `1712.../fastq/` would have one). Thanks.